# String searching - parallel version is slower

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to paralelize naive algorithm for string searching. I created simple version and then I tried to speed it up, using multiple threads.

But following code makes it much slower:

```
template<typename T> long unsigned int simple_paralel(const T * str1, unsigned long int str1_length, const T * str2, unsigned long int str2_length) {
  unsigned int long result = ~0;
  unsigned int long count = 0;

  unsigned long int in;
  unsigned int long top;
  #pragma omp parallel
  #pragma for ordered shared(result, count) private(in, top) firstprivate(str1, str2, str1_length, str2_length)
  for (top = 0; top < str1_length; top++) {
    in = 0;

    // & top + in < str1_length
    while (in < str2_length ) {
      if ( top + in >= str1_length)
        break;

      if ( str1[top+in] != str2[in] ) {
        break;
      }
      ++in;

      if( in == str2_length ) {
        // shared and we want to have the smallest index
        if( result >= top + 1 ) {
          result = top + 1;
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Random guess: Not enough work in each thread to compensate for the overhead around starting/stopping/collating results?

Comment: May be - many while cycles will immediatelly end, because no match was found. How to solve this?

Comment: It's hard for me to say, since I don't know the exact details of the particular problem you're trying to solve (I understand the basics, but there are lots of details, such as how large strings are, how many there are, how much of the first part of the string matches before it bails out, are they sorted or not, can they be sorted, etc - I'm sure I've not thought of ALL things that matter here). Generally, the LONGER each thread runs separately from others, the better performance you'll get from running in parallel.

Comment: You do realize your 2nd `#pragma` is wrong, right? You are missing the `omp` in it, making it a simple comment that the compiler ignores. I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, but what's for sure is that without this `omp` in the directive, it won't get any faster when compiled with OpenMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stepped back and tried a different approach:

```
template<typename T> long unsigned int simple_paralel(const T * str1, unsigned long int str1_length, const T * str2, unsigned long int str2_length, int threads) {
  count = 0;

  unsigned long int block = str1_length/threads;
  unsigned long int total = 0;
  unsigned long int result = 0;

  unsigned long int smallest = ~0;
  #pragma omp parallel for shared(count)
  for(int i=0; i<threads; i++)
  {
    unsigned long int res;
    unsigned long int start = i * block;
    if(i != threads -1 )
    {
      total += block;
      res = simple_p(str1 + start, block, str2, str2_length, false);
    } else {
      res = simple_p(str1 + start, str1_length - total, str2, str2_length);
    }

    if(res < result && res != 0 ){
      result = res;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

And it works as expected. But I still **can't believe**, that I **cannot do this with OpenMP**.

Comment: ***But I still can't believe, that I cannot do this with OpenMP.*** I am confused with this statement. It looks like you are using openmp here. Was this meant to be an answer that solves the problem?

Comment: My bad! I meant: I thought, that OpenMP could easily split input into chunks, like my solution.